# Tracking object in realtime using depth image stream from a RGBD camera

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm, sensors, computer-vision, stereo-vision

I have an Intel RealSense camera which can stream RGB and depth image. Using those information I want to track an object moving on a table top. More specifically, I want to know position $(x,y)$ and orientation $\theta_z$ of the object. Can any body help providing me the pipeline for accomplishing what I mentioned? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This problem is quite vast, thus many different techniques can be employed depending on the level of accuracy you need to achieve and the amount of information you have available. It would help narrow it down if you can provide more details, such as:
- is the scene cluttered or you have only one object on the table?
- do you have any _a-priori_ info on the object (e.g. 3D model)?

Comment: There is only one object on the table (no cluttered environment). Also object's physical dimensions are known.